# multiple 2 thread 3-assignment using three compare and set objects

Tags: multithreading, compare-and-swap, consensus, multiple-assignment

I'm working my way through the book 'The Art of Multiprocessor Programming' and am stuck on a certain question. The question as well as a proposed solution can be found [here](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p50m1c3/Show-that-an-n-bounded-compareAndSet-object-has-consensus-number-ex-actly-n/) (Question 71)

My issue is that their solution does not seem correct to me. An Assign23 object must be able to set 2 of the 3 values when a thread calls the assign method and the result must have a consensus of 2.

In other words If thread A and thread B call assign, both wanting to write to r[0] and r[1], A manages to get its value into r[0] and B into r[1], then we have an illegal situation. Thread A thinks it set its two values and so does B while in reality neither achieved their goal.
Am I misunderstanding something in their solution?

Have you got a better option? I can not seem to come up with something that works for all cases.

Comment: The `assign` method is `synchronized` which prevents two threads from entering the method at the same time (at least in Java). But by using `synchronized` the whole `compareAndSet` thing becomes superfluous - I guess I don't get the point of the exercise/solution either.